# Search engine from scratch

Tags: python, mysql, search, search-engine

I have a MySQL database with around 10,000 articles in it, but that number will probably go up with time. I want to be able to search through these articles and pull out the most relevent results based on some keywords. I know there are a number of projects that I can plug into that can essentially do this for me. However, the application for this is very simple, and it would be nice to have direct control and working knowledge of how the whole thing operates. Therefore, I would like to look into building a very simple search engine from scratch in Python.

I'm not even sure where to start, really. I could just dump everything from the MySQL DB into a list and try to sort that list based on relevance, however that seems like it would be slow, and get slower as the amount of database items increase. I could use some basic MySQL search to get the top 100 most relevant results from what MySQL thinks, then sort those 100. But that is a two step process which may be less efficient, and I might risk missing an article if it is just out of range.

What are the best approaches I can take to this?

Comment: I bet Google has a *ton* of starting points for this.. What have you even tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried anything, as I am just planning my approach. The things I have found all employ a pure MySQL search, or dump the articles into a list and sort through.

Answer (score 3):

The best bet for you to do "Search Engine" for the 10,000 Articles is to read "**Programming Collective Intelligence" by Toby Segaran**. Wonderful read and to save your time go to Chapter 4 of August 2007 issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind replacing the MySQL database with something else then I suggest [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/), using [pyes](http://pythonhosted.org/pyes/manual/usage.html).

It has the functionality you would expect of a search engine, including full text search, great performance, pagination, more-like-this, plugin-able scoring algorithm, and is real time - so when more data is added it will be instantly shown in the search results.

If you dont want to remove the current database then you can easily run them side by side, and treat the MySQL as the master.